# onreadystatechange readystate=1 but not 2, 3 or 4

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

This is my first request for help at stackoverflow, so, please, be gentle.

I've searched stackoverflow for questions on this, but haven't found anything that addresses my issue in a way that has allowed me to solve my problem.

I'm trying to use php to send an email containing a user's password from a webpage.  I'm using Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.2.7 Safari/537.85.16 as my browser--but I need it work from any major modern browser.

Now https://pie.gd/test/script-link-events/ seems to indicate that is not supported by my browser, nor by *any* Mac browser, but that doesn't seem to be consistent with my experience--none of my browser's consoles through an error with my use of `onreadystatechange`.

The javascript code I'm using is:

```
    function forgotEmail(str_code)
    {
        bool_debug = <?php echo $bool_debug ?>;

        if (bool_debug) { alert("php/forgotEmail.php?"+str_code+" is being called."); } 

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } // if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        else 
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } // if (window.XMLHttpRequest) else

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            alert("readyState = " + xmlhttp.readyState + "\nstatus=" + xmlhttp.status)

            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) 
            {
                alert("readyState = " + xmlhttp.readyState + "\nstatus=" + xmlhttp.status)
                if (xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    alert("An email with your password has been sent to the account you gave with your CO Gold submission.  It may take a few minutes to arrive.  Please also check your spam folder.");
                } // if (xmlhttp.status==200)
            } // if ((xmlhttp.readyState==4) && (xmlhttp.status==200))
            else
            {
                alert("There was a problem sending the email with your password.  Please click 'Forgot Password' again.  If you get this alert a third time, please email...");
            } // if ((xmlhttp.readyState==4) && (xmlhttp.status==200)) else
        } // xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "php/forgotEmail.php?"+str_code);

    } // function forgotEmail(str_code)
```

and the relevant code from the php page being called by `AJAX` is:

```
…
$headers = 'From: <a valid email address>'."\r\n";
// the message
$str_body = $row_psswd['NameFirst'].",\n\n"
    .'Your password is:  '.$row_psswd['psswd']."\n\n";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$str_body = wordwrap($str_body,90);

// send email
$return = mail($row_psswd['Email'], "Forgotten Password", $str_body, $headers); 

echo str_replace("\n", "<br />\n", $str_body);

echo "<br />\n<br />\n";
echo (($return) ? 'email sent' :  'email not sent');
```

Now, when I call the php page by hand, the email gets sent no problem.

But when I click on the HTML button in the webpage that calls the javascript, no email gets sent.  I know the `php` page is being called correctly, because I get:

`php/forgotEmail.php?code=JIxRIt is being called.`

from my first debug `alert` in the javascript code.  But I only get one `alert` from within the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()`:

`readyState = 1
status=0`

and then the "things haven't worked" `alert`:

`There was a problem sending the email with your password.  Please click 'Forgot Password' again.  If you get this alert a third time, please email…`

So it would appear that `readyState` is never taking on the values 2, 3 or 4--not taking on the value 4 indicates that the email isn't getting sent, right?

But the fact that that I'm getting an

`readyState = 1
status=0`

makes me think that `onreadystatechange` is, in fact, supported by Safari (for the Mac).

I hope I've stated the issue clearly and that somebody will be able to help me with this as it's frustrating the @$^&$%@ out of me.

Comment: Could you please give me an example for `str_code` in your JS code? How does your query string look like?

Comment: `readyState == 1` doesn't mean there was a problem. XHR goes through several stages, and `readyState` reports the current stage. See the list of states at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: In your code, where are you calling `send()`?

Comment: @Barmar -- I understand that there are four states for onReady--my question is why I'm not seeing onReady=2, onReady=3 or onReady=4. –

Comment: @litelite Of all the obvious things!  Seesh!  Thank you!!!

If you want to post this as an answer, I'll mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `send()` method to send your request to the server

```
xmlhttp.send()
```

Also, you should to move your "thing did not work" code because, right now any readyState that is not 4 will trigger it.

```
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            alert("readyState = " + xmlhttp.readyState + "\nstatus=" + xmlhttp.status)

            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) 
            {
                alert("readyState = " + xmlhttp.readyState + "\nstatus=" + xmlhttp.status)
                if (xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    alert("An email with your password has been sent to the account you gave with your CO Gold submission.  It may take a few minutes to arrive.  Please also check your spam folder.");
                } // if (xmlhttp.status==200)
            } // if ((xmlhttp.readyState==4) && (xmlhttp.status==200))
            else
            {
                alert("There was a problem sending the email with your password.  Please click 'Forgot Password' again.  If you get this alert a third time, please email...");
            } // if ((xmlhttp.readyState==4) && (xmlhttp.status==200)) else
        } // xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
```

becomes

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            alert("readyState = " + xmlhttp.readyState + "\nstatus=" + xmlhttp.status)

            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) 
            {
                alert("readyState = " + xmlhttp.readyState + "\nstatus=" + xmlhttp.status)
                if (xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    alert("An email with your password has been sent to the account you gave with your CO Gold submission.  It may take a few minutes to arrive.  Please also check your spam folder.");
                } // if (xmlhttp.status==200)
                else
                {
                    alert("There was a problem sending the email with your password.  Please click 'Forgot Password' again.  If you get this alert a third time, please email...");
                } // if ((xmlhttp.readyState==4) && (xmlhttp.status==200)) else
            } // if ((xmlhttp.readyState==4) && (xmlhttp.status==200))
        } // xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
```

Comment: litelite -- I understand your point, but this is no the issue I'm worried about.

I'm worried about why I'm not seeing readystate=2, 3 or 4, and why my email not's getting sent when I click the the web button but it is when I load the php page by hand with the out of the first alert.

Comment: @JamesNorris when responding to people please use proper notation (@ before the name) this way, people will receive a notification when you send a comment (the person that wrote the answer or question being commented will also receive a notification)

Comment: @litlite -- sorry, didn't know that's how that works.